# Flutter - Solicitando dados de uma API REST que retorna um List e não um Map

Tags: rest, flutter

Olá, pessoal.

Estou iniciando agora no Flutter, e me deparei com um perrengue :/

Eu aprendi em um curso na web, que através do json retornado da requisição eu posso usar ele como um Map no Flutter.

Porem, o Flutter entende esse meu retorno como um List, e eu não consigo usar como um Map. Minha intensão era alimentar um objeto Pessoa com os dados desse Map. Vejam o código abaixo.

Este é o json retornado da Api REST:

[image: Retorno Json]

Aqui é aonde eu estou fazendo a requisição, eu estou tendo que retornar um List, pois dava o erro de que ao invés de um Map, meu retorno se tratava de um List.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, eu não consigo utilizar o meu construtor .fromMap().
Como eu posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, evite usar imagens de textos. Para ajudar os colaboradores, use as ferramentas de formatação e coloque o texto, em vez das imagens.

Comment: já tentou usar o [`Map.fromIterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html) no lugar de `fromMap` ?

Answer (score -1):

eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Ao invés de retornar um list no meu obter usuário, eu retornei o Http.Response.

Na minha classe que fez a requisição, eu usei o Iterable.

```
Future<bool?> validarUsuario(String usuario, String senha) async {
List<Usuario> usuarios = [];

await _usuarioController.obterUsuario(usuario: usuario).then((response) {
  Iterable list = jsonDecode(response.body);
  usuarios = list.map((e) => Usuario.fromMap(e)).toList();
});

return usuarios.first.usuSenha == senha ? true : false;
```

}

Eu não entendi muito, em alguns servidores REST eu consigo retornar direto como um Map, mas neste meu servidor em Pascal, meu código não deixa eu usar o resultado como Map.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, o json retornado é de fato uma lista, veja que o formato dele estar como

```
[
    {
    }
]
```

ele seria um Map se estivesse no formato

```
{
}
```

o que você tem é uma lista de Map, para tratá-lo como um Map você pode ou percorrer o response através de um for ou se ele possuir apenas uma objeto sempre, acessar pelo response.body[0]

Você pode tbm converter esses dados usando o código

```
List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body)
return body.map((json) => Usuario.fromMap(json)).toList()
```